# How to create registry on multiple remote machine

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a registry key on remote machine with below code:

```
$basePath="C:\Users\<User>\Desktop\Script\"
$remoteMachineName = $basePath + "server.txt"
$arrServer=(Get-Content $remoteMachineName)

$remoteUserPassword = Get-Content "C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\Script\pass.txt"
ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String $password
$credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "UserName"

   Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $credentials
New-ItemProperty -Name "myReg" -Value "ABC" -PropertyType "String" -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Usertest"
```

But it creates registry key on my local machine however I want it on remote machine giving below error :

```
New-ItemProperty : The property already exists.
At C:\Users\<User>\Desktop\Script\Untitled4.ps1:14 char:1
+ New-ItemProperty -Name "myReg" -Value "ABC" -PropertyType " ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Usertest\:String) [New-ItemProperty], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemPropertyCommand
```

But when I run command `Enter-PSSession` and `New-ItemProperty` separately it works but I want to run both the commands simultaneously.

Please Help me to create registry Key on remote machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet:

```
# ...
Invoke-Command -cn $server -cred $credentials {
    New-ItemProperty -Name "myReg" -Value "ABC" -PropertyType "String" -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Usertest" -Force
}
```

Comment: I tried with `-force` as well But it's not working it just creating the registry key on my local machine instead of remote machine.